# Why are my embedded fonts not working in Firefox only?

Tags: firefox, font-face

All of sudden today my web fonts are not working in Firefox only.  So strange.  It was working yesterday.  Nothing changed.

[Here is my website.](https://www.paperboxtalent.com)

```
@font-face {
     font-family: 'Gotham Condensed';
     src: url('https://www.paperboxtalent.com/fonts/GothamCondensed-Light.woff2') format('woff2'), url('https://www.paperboxtalent.com/fonts/GothamCondensed-Light.woff') format('woff'), url('https://www.paperboxtalent.com/fonts/GothamCondensed-Light.svg#GothamCondensed-Light') format('svg');
     font-weight: 300;
     font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just realized I was looking at the http and not https